# How to display data as a range in a single cell? (google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number that represents a starting point. What I need to do is to create different "Levels"(using formulas) based on that number and display those in a single cell

Example:

```
Max Speed 60 Mph

Level 1   10-15
Level 2   16-21
....
Level 7   55-60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. In B2 put 60. Then in B4 put:

```
=int(B2*10/60)&"-"&int(B2*15/60)
```

In B5 put:

```
=int(B2*16/60)&"-"&int(B2*21/60)
```

And so on for the different levels.